# Splash screen really small on iOS

Tags: .net, maui

I'm having trouble with the splash screen only on iOS. Android is fine when it loads the same image. On iOS it is really small though. I have:

```
<MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\pumppallogo.svg" BaseSize="128,128" Resize="true" Color="#512BD4" />
```

the image size is 400 x 400 SVG format. Not sure what I can do to get this to show correctly?

Comment: What happens if you increase BaseSize to "256,256"?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it, but doesn't seem to help.

Comment: It looks like on a fresh project with all the same code and same image it loads correctly. So maybe a cashing problem somewhere.

Comment: See [comment in known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11160#issuecomment-1307939002). Says `resize="true"` works in *"net7 update (maui workloads - 7.0.49/7.0.100"*. Compare the .csproj files of the two projects. Is original one targetting net6? Re caching, delete hidden .vs folder, and .bin and .obj folders.

Comment: Which .NET version are you using? It should be fixed in the latest .NET 7.0 MAUI workload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did to fix the issue was erased all data on my device. This didn't work but figured I would mention it because I did do this.

But ultimately I renamed the splash screen file and then deleted the .vs,bin and object folders. Delete the app from device, clean and rebuild the solution.